# How to break in a <ui:repeat>

Tags: jsf, loops, facelets, break

Is there any easy way I can break in a ui:repeat loop ?

I'm trying to do it the following way, but it does not work. The idea is to print the image when, requestScope.counter == 1.

```
    <c:set target="#{requestScope}" property="counter" value="0" />
    <ui:repeat var="mediaVar" value="#{brandsVar.brandBrandMedia}" >

<ui:fragment rendered="#{mediaVar.bmType eq 'image'}">
    <ui:param name="#{requestScope.counter}" value="#{requestScope.counter + 1}" />
</ui:fragment>

<h:graphicImage rendered="#{mediaVar.bmType eq 'image' &amp;&amp;  requestScope.counter == 1}"
height="100" width="100"
value="location of image" />
    </ui:repeat>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't break in an `ui:repeat`. As to your concrete problem, use `and` instead of `&amp;&amp;`.

Comment: Thanks BalusC.
So is this (The way I am doing it now) the best solution for the problem I mentioned above ?

Comment: The functional requirement is not clear, so I can't tell if it is the best solution.

Comment: I changed my model to avoid such cases and it's fine now. thanks for your pointers BalusC.